# IBOutlet in ARC releases and sets to nil. How to avoid this? objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard, automatic-ref-counting

I'm new to ARC and Storyboarding. I've set `IBOutlet` to `UITableView` from my `UIViewController`.
After some time my `IBOutlet` sets to nil and I can't reload it from other classes.
Here is my `dataTable` `IBOutlet`:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *dataTable;
```

At the start `dataTable` is not `nil`, but not when I try to access it from another class (via appDelegate). How to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**
I call this method from my `UIViewController`

```
[appDelegate.myClass loginWithUserName:loginField.text andPassword:pwdField.text];
```

When it's done, and I have data to show, I call this code from `loginWithUserName` method:

```
   MyViewController *controller = [[AppDelegate sharedStoryboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
   [controller audioLoaded];
```

And here is that method in my `UIViewController`, wich reloads data

```
 -(void) audioLoaded
 {
    //it is nil here
    [self.dataTable reloadData];
 }
```

Comment: are you sure you've connected all the appropriate outlets in interface builder?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. I think problem in instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property to strong retain the object:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *dataTable;
```

It's not good practice to access a UITableView from another view controller though..

EDIT:

You shoul reconsider the whole approach, by moving that logic from your appdelegate to a dedicated class that will perform the login. You can create a simple protocol that the UIViewController with the table can implement, then, when calling the login method, pass a reference to the current viewcontroller, something like

```
loginWithUserName:andPassword:andCaller:(id<LoginDelegate>)sender
```

Where LoginDelegate is something on this line:

```
@protocol LoginDelegate
- (void)audioLoaded;
@end
```

In this way you can just call

```
[sender audioLoaded];
```

Comment: +1. You really shouldn't be accessing another view controller's nib file.

Comment: No, no. I call method reloadMyDataTable from other class. This method in same UIViewController

Comment: You are still performing operations on a table view that's not visible. No need to do that from another view controller. Can't you perform the reloadData on viewWillAppear?

Comment: But my UIViewController is focused, It's not dissapeared. And strong not helps, it is nil

Comment: Can you update the question with more code then? Maybe the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: you're instantiating a new view controller in that code, you're not referring to the one that's already visible, therefore th UITableView is still nil when you call it. You shoul reconsider the whole approach, by moving that logic from your appdelegate to a dedicated class that will perform the login. Then, when calling the login method, pass a reference to the current viewcontroller, something like loginWithUserName:andPassword:andCaller:(id)sender... in this way you can just call [sender audioLoaded];

Comment: @andreamazz i've done this allreadey, but what if i'll make reference in appDelegate property as strong type? Is this correct when I'm working in ARC?